# TeamCity Cannot exec: No such file or directory

Tags: azure, teamcity

I'm new to TeamCity (literally started about 4h ago) and I'm trying to setup my own build server. It's "technically" working, but I can't run a successful build because of some minor issues I think might be related to setting up the server.

The first problem I had was regarding npm, I tried to run the command line npm and it wouldn't work. I fixed that by installing the Node.js NPM plugin for teamcity. Now the problem is related to `bzip2`:

```
[20:06:06][npm install] Error extracting archive
[20:06:06][npm install] Phantom installation failed { Error: Command failed: tar jxf /opt/buildagent/temp/buildTmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
[20:06:06][npm install] tar (child): bzip2: Cannot exec: No such file or directory
[20:06:06][npm install] tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
[20:06:06][npm install] tar: Child returned status 2
[20:06:06][npm install] tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I'd love to get the answer for that problem, but also if there's anything I need to do to setup TeamCity properly. I did some research, but couldn't find anything specific. Actually it even looks like I'm the only one to experience these issues?...

I read the online docs for TeamCity and Google with no luck.

I'm using a professional TeamCity instance running on Azure (TeamCity Professional 2017.2.2 (build 50909))

Before every build I need to run the npm installer (using the plugin). Is there a way to install it globally on the agent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you build-agent, where the command is executing, lacks some dependencies:

```
bzip2: Cannot exec: No such file or directory
```

Seems like you need `bzip2` and `bzip2-libs` packages.

Comment: Thank you, I did notice that as mentioned on my question, I need to know how to install it globally now. If you have information that could help, I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have experience working with Azure, but assuming you have Debian based distributive, you can ssh to the build-agent and run this: `sudo apt-get install bzip2`.

Comment: Let me try that, I'll get back to you in a sec. Thanks.

Comment: It's taking me some time because I found out it's coreOS and now I'm trying to find out how to install libs there. I'll update here as soon as I can test it. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, I did try it, but it doesn't seem to have worked. Do you if there's a specific place I should install that? I logged in via SSH, used dnf to install nodejs and bzip2 and it is working as seen by the output of the commands: `[root@teamcity ~]# npm --version  
5.6.0
[root@teamcity ~]# node --version
v8.9.4` but TeamCity is still not recognizing the commands. Is there a specific place to install those tools, do you know that?

Comment: They should be install globally. Try copying the command from TeamCity and execute it from ssh in the terminal.

Comment: I did... thanks for you help, but still nothing so far, I was even studying the source code of https://github.com/jonnyzzz/TeamCity.Node/blob/c15edba1ba01b4ad1314dbc02d4e105d8054c82b/agent/src/main/java/com/jonnyzzz/teamcity/plugins/node/agent/nvm/NVM.kt to understand how he installs nodeJS on the agent, but even after installing nvm/node/npm on the container and "globally" the build process still throws an error, not recognizing node. There must be something pretty basic about teamcity's agents structure I'm missing here...